# The intent in notification does not work

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

My notification is a service (service.java) and what the service do is start a notification of battery level when a checkboxpreference in the preference screen is checked.. What not works now is the intent to enter in the `MainActivity` clicking the notification. This is the code

```
if(mprefs.getBoolean("notification_a", false)==true){
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("Battery Stats Informations");
    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Carica residua: " +level+"%" + " " + "Temperatura: " +temperature+ "°C");
    //notificationBuilder.setTicker("Informazioni batteria");
    notificationBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small_not);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    Notification not=notificationBuilder.build();

    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTIFICATION_ID,not);
} else {
    mNotificationManager.cancelAll();
}
```

The intent `Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class` doesn't work. Any helps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you intend to start the Activity when Notification is clicked:
Use:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a new activity, like calling
>   Context.startActivity(Intent).

in place of:

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
```

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast, like calling
>   Context.sendBroadcast().

Comment: Well, then i try.. but which is the different between `getActivity` and `getBroadcast`?